# Firefox web extension, content script registration example not working for other websites

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Examples

Code here:
https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/main/content-script-register

The above example from Firefox's own documentation does not appear to work as expected. Here is the main JS for the extension:

```js
'use strict';

const hostsInput =  document.querySelector("#hosts");
const codeInput =  document.querySelector("#code");

const defaultHosts = "*://*.org/*";
const defaultCode = "document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>This page has been eaten</h1>'";

hostsInput.value = defaultHosts;
codeInput.value = defaultCode;

function registerScript() {
  browser.runtime.sendMessage({
    hosts: hostsInput.value.split(","),
    code: codeInput.value
  });
}

document.querySelector("#register").addEventListener('click', registerScript);
```

You can see the line `const defaultHosts = "*://*.org/*";` which works as expected, however no matter what I do I cannot get it to work for i.e. `const defaultHosts = *reddit.com/*` or `*://*google*` etc.

Any ideas why it might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [match pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Match_patterns) must specify scheme://host/path, so the first pattern will be `*://*.reddit.com/*`

A match pattern's last domain cannot be `*`, so the second pattern cannot be fixed and you'll have to list all top-level domains explicitly ([example](/a/11069916)).

P.S. Although it's also possible to use `includeGlobs: ['*.google.*/']` when registering the content script in the background script, but it's a terrible workaround as it'll match the text in the wrong part of a URL like `/path/` or `search?parameter=value`.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes much more sense now, thank you!